# How change layered navigation filters orientation from vertical to horizontal on product page in magento 2.3

Tags: magento2, product, layered-navigation, filter

How change layered navigation  filter orientation from vertical to horizontal? Now I have vertical-orientated filters, but I want to change them to horizontal. 
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ashen,

If you want overall listing page layered navigation should be in horizontal, then change your listing page layout from 2columns-left to 1column in catalog_category_view.xml file.

If it needs for specific category, then set 1column layout from backend.

Note: make sure your theme is overwritten or parent by luma theme.