# Change Active filter position Magento 2

Tags: magento2, layered-navigation, filter, state

I want to update the Active filter position from left side to right side just above the product listing. Please guide me how can i do that.

**Current Position: On left side**

[image]

**Required Position: I want to display on the right side**

[image]

I tried using the layout xml files but it did not work for me. If you guys have an alternate solution please provide me. Your help would be appriciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Check this out! [How change layered navigation filters orientation from vertical to horizontal on product page in magento 2.3](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/273302/96089)

Comment: I need two-column but all the active filter should display above the product listing.

Answer (score 1):

Please add the below code in your custom module :

**app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/layout/catalog_catagory_view_type_layered.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <attribute name="class" value="page-with-filter"/>
        <referenceContainer name="sidebar.main">
            <block class="Magento\LayeredNavigation\Block\Navigation\Category" name="catalog.leftnav" before="-" template="Magento_LayeredNavigation::layer/view.phtml">
                <block class="Magento\LayeredNavigation\Block\Navigation\State" name="catalog.navigation.state" as="state" />
                <block class="Magento\LayeredNavigation\Block\Navigation\FilterRenderer" name="catalog.navigation.renderer" as="renderer" template="Magento_LayeredNavigation::layer/filter.phtml">
                    <arguments>
                        <argument name="product_layer_view_model" xsi:type="object">Magento\LayeredNavigation\ViewModel\Layer\Filter</argument>
                    </arguments>
                </block>
            </block>
        </referenceContainer>
        <move element="catalog.navigation.state" destination="content" before="category.products" />
    </body>
</page>
```

Then override the **Navigation.php** file and edit in the following function
and then add the following in the **navigation.php** file
**Vendor/Module/Block/Navigation.php**

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
namespace Magento\LayeredNavigation\Block;

use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection;
use Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar;

/**
 * Catalog layered navigation view block
 *
 * @api
 * @since 100.0.2
 */
class Navigation extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
    public function getClearUrl()
    {
        
        return $this->getChildBlock('state') ?$this->getChildBlock('state')->getClearUrl():"";
    }
}
?>
```

Then create the **di.xml** file and override the **Navigation.php** file using the preference method
**Vendor/Module/etc/di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\LayeredNavigation\Block\Navigation" type="Vendor\Magento\Block\Navigation" />
</config>
```

Now, Add **Magento_LayeredNavigation** in the sequence tag of your module.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--/**
* Copyright © 2020 Grazitti . All rights reserved.
*/-->
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Vendor_Magento" setup_version="2.0.3">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_LayeredNavigation"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

Comment: I am facing this error, <a href="Error: Call to a member function getClearUrl() on bool in /var/www/html/opt-staging/vendor/magento/module-layered-navigation/Block/Navigation.php:136

could not override the Navigation.php file

Comment: @SunnyRahevar updated the answer you have to add the "Magento_LayeredNavigation" in the sequence tag in "module.xml" file. Please accept the answer if it works